# Flask custom command not found in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, sqlalchemy, click

I'm running a simple Flask app in docker container and i wrote a custom command that would help creating superuser in the postgres table.
The custom flask command snippet

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


@click.command(name="create_superuser")
@click.argument("login")
@click.argument("email")
@click.argument("password")
def create_superuser(login:str, email:str, password:str):
    db_user = User(login=login,
                   email=email)
    db_user.set_password(password)
    session.add(db_user)
    session.commit()
    return {
        "id": db_user.id,
        "login": db_user.login,
        "email": db_user.email,
    }
app.cli.add_command(create_superuser)
```

my container is up, and entering terminal using **docker exec -it containername bash**
inside terminal i'm calling the following code

```
root@d03447bc8819:/auth_api# flask create_superuser admin admin@admin.com admin
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. Use the 'flask --app' option, 'FLASK_APP' environment variable, or a 'wsgi.py' or 'app.py' file in the current directory.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'create_superuser'.
```

Tried this **$env:FLASK_APP = "flaskblog.py"** with no success after.
Thanks in advance for ideas/solutions..

Comment: Please tell us what container you are using. If you built the container yourself, then include the Dockerfile. What command do you use to start the container?

Comment: **Dockerfile**
`FROM python:3.10.8-bullseye

ENV \
    PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/python3 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir -p /auth_api
COPY ./ /auth_api
RUN \
    pip install --upgrade wheel \
    && python3 -m pip install -r /auth_api/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /auth_api

EXPOSE 8000

CMD alembic upgrade head && python main.py`